# Can't boot into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS “Try (hd0,0): EXT2: I/O error _ " Message

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8. The installation was error less but when I try to boot with ubuntu, I  got following error:

Try (hd0,0): EXT2: I/O error _

But when I press ctrl+alt+del and restart the computer I got windows welcome screen and the windows 8 worked fine. But when I chose to boot with ubuntu, same thing happened again.

Answer (score 0):

well I checked this error and it seems to be because you tried to "install inside windows"? if so, please check this thread, might me a solution there: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1413634